# elseif when mysql query didn't return any rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a simple timeclock system that allows employees to log their working hours.

I have a table that stores the timestamps and weather it was a clock-in or clock-out action. Depending on the last action for a given user, the opposite options are presented. For example, if the last action was clock-out then the presented action should be clock-in.

In a scenario where the user has not used the system before they should be presented with an option to clock-in.

```
$sql_status = "SELECT * FROM timeclock WHERE employeeid = $employee_number ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($result=$mysqli->query($sql_status)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        $timeclock_action = $row[2];
        $timeclock_timestamp = $row[3];
            if($timeclock_action=="out") {
                $forward_action = "clockin";
                $forward_action_label = "Clock in";
                $timeclock_status_label = "Last clock out: ";
            } elseif($timeclock_action=="in") {
                $forward_action = "clockout";
                $forward_action_label = "Clock out";
                $timeclock_status_label = "Clocked in: ";
            }
    }
} elseif(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
    $forward_action = "clockin";
    $forward_action_label = "Clock in";
    $timeclock_status_label = "You've never clocked in before";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

My thought process is that elseif mysql query returns 0 rows, the variables would be set accordingly, but they don't get set at all.
Where am I wrong in my thinking? Thanks!

Comment: If there are no results, there will still be a $result. Move that check into the if block, and possibly create a new if/else block there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current logic is that if the query *failed* - that is when the query returned *false* (not that it didn't return any results, but that the execution altogether failed), you check if the number of rows returned was zero.

Instead, you should execute the query first, then check if there were any rows returned. You also don't need to loop for multiple rows, as you only expect one row with `LIMIT 1` in the query.

You should also look into using a prepared statement instead of injecting variables directly in the query, and doing some other error-handling; as errors should never be displayed directly to the user (log the errors, and display a generic "Something went wrong" message).

```
// The query to be executed
$sql_status = "SELECT * FROM timeclock WHERE employeeid = $employee_number ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

// See if the query was successful or not
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql_status)) {
    // If there are any rows returned
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        // Fetch rows - no need for a loop since you only expect one record (LIMIT 1 in the query)
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        $timeclock_action = $row[2];
        $timeclock_timestamp = $row[3];

        if ($timeclock_action=="out") {
            $forward_action = "clockin";
            $forward_action_label = "Clock in";
            $timeclock_status_label = "Last clock out: ";
        } elseif ($timeclock_action=="in") {
            $forward_action = "clockout";
            $forward_action_label = "Clock out";
            $timeclock_status_label = "Clocked in: ";
        }
    } else {
        $forward_action = "clockin";
        $forward_action_label = "Clock in";
        $timeclock_status_label = "You've never clocked in before";
    }
} else {
    // The query failed
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Qirel! Also goes to show that I should make a habit of commenting on my code as it also allows to think the logic through better. P.S. There is one extra closing parenthesis in `$row = $results->fetch_row();`

Comment: Ah, thanks for letting me know! I'll edit that out :-) Feel free to accept this answer if this turned out to be the solution for you. Cheers!